# Composing functionality of sealed class with interfaces

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, classes, interface

```
public sealed class Client
{
    private Simulation _simulation;
    public Client(ITickProvider tickProvider, ICommandReceiver commandReceiver)
    {
        _simulation = new Simulation();
       tickProvider.Tick += HandleTick;
       commandReceiver.CommandReceived += HandleCommandReceived;
    }
    private void HandleTick ()
    {
        //Distribute tick to _simulation
    }
    private void HandleCommandReceived(Command command)
    {
        //Inject command to _simulation
    }
}
```

`Client` operates a multithreaded Simulation, distributing ticks and external input to the Simulation.

`ITickProvider` provides a Tick event that runs every e.g. fixed interval, button click, etc..

`ICommandReceiver` receives external input (Commands); i.e. User input, server input, serialized input, etc..

Because the interfaces' implementations are usually exclusive, I decided to make Client sealed and inject the functionality with the constructor. This also helps with controlling thread-sensitive access to Simulation.

What is the pattern of composing a sealed class with modular interfaces? Is this a well-known pattern and if so, have I implemented it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the actual class requirements along with the overall code factors.
For instance,

- Do you think that `Client` class can be extended in the future? *(not by inheritance surely since it's `sealed`)*.
- How often this class is going to be called?
- How simple you need to simplify the initiation of this class? *(as a way to automate handling of its dependencies)*
- Are these interfaces going to be recalled or extended in any other way except this class ?
- Do interfaces have many `unneeded` members? *(say you only need some members and not all of them).*

You must investigate that, and decide the best approach that would be feasible to your current project.

As kick-starter that would give you some ideas after looking at your class, and interfaces, without knowing your actual implementations, I could say the safest way is to create `ClientHandler` and pass it to the constructor instead. something like this :

```
public class ClientHandler : ITickProvider, ICommandReceiver
{
    private readonly Simulation _simulation;
    public ClientHandler(Simulation simulation)
    {
        if(simulation == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullExecption(nameof(simulation));
        }
        _simulation = simulation;
    }
    
    // ITickProvider implementation
    // Do the handeling here 
    public void Tick() { ... }

    // ICommandReceiver implementation
    // Do the handeling here 
    public void CommandReceived() { ... }
}

public sealed class Client
{
    private readonly ClientHandler _handler; 
    
    public Client(ClientHandler clientHandler)
    {
        if(clientHandler == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullExecption(nameof(clientHandler));
        }
        
        _handler = clientHandler;           
    }
}
```

This is better, because you'll have more room in your code to be able to control the handler and the client side-by-side, with a benefit of extending the handler as per requirement. Also, Implementing interfaces would ease your work, especially if your work includes `Reflection`. You can also keep the handler as `abstract class` and inherit it to have more customizable handlers.